# Is using saliva as a dive mask defogger dangerous?

Tags: medical-science, hygiene

When diving, you can use [saliva](http://www.thescubaguide.com/mailbag/qa019.aspx) or [commercial defog](http://www.mcnett.com/Sea-Gold-Anti-Fog-Gel-for-Dive-Masks-P231.aspx) to prevent your mask from fogging. However, according to [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Defog-a-Diving-Mask), bacteria in saliva are potentially harmful to your eyes.

> Beware of using spit - there are a lot of bugs in saliva that you don't want in your eyes.

Is there any substantive risk of getting a bacterial infection in your eyes in this way?

Comment: The fill quote is "*some say* beware of this...". Even WikiHow isn't convinced. And how does the saliva get from the glass to your eyes?

Comment: I do this all the time, when sea weeds are not available. Otherwise I find the moss/plants stuck to rocks underwater to work better than spit.

Comment: If you put so much spit in your mask that your eyes flood, you're overdoing it.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. Remember that during a lengthy dive water may well enter the mask and have to be blown out. This does pose a significant risk of getting eyes exposed to eventual bacteria.

Comment: Well your tear ducts open up into your nasal passage which is linked directly to your mouth so I would suggest it can't be that dangerous.  It's not very far for bugs to travel to do some damage, lets face it everybody has spurted coke out of thier nose at some point...

Comment: Hmm.  Never had any particular problem (and I've been diving for years all around the world) but I do find the question interesting.

Comment: I've been told not to wear contacts while diving but it was the bacteria in the *seawater* about which the doctor was concerned.